# Casperjs export XML to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, xunit, casperjs

I successfully setup a casperjs test exporting a "result.xml" file.

In Jenkins, I execute the following shell command:

```
casperjs /home/testing-radu/generated-test.js
```

This produces "results.xml" in my build's workspace.

In post-build actions I added "Publish XUnit test result report". I don't know how and where to setup the path to the .xml file.

When my build console I see the following:

```
[37;42;1mPASS 2 tests executed in 9.96s, 2 passed, 0 failed.                             [0m
[32;1mResult log stored in results.xml                                                [0m
[xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
ERROR: Publisher org.jenkinsci.plugins.xunit.XUnitPublisher aborted due to exception
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/17live2/workspace/generatedJUnitFiles does not exist.
```

I added full rights to the workspace directory. I tried creating "generatedJUnitFiles" folder and here is what I'm getting:

```
[37;42;1mPASS 2 tests executed in 5.296s, 2 passed, 0 failed.                            [0m
[32;1mResult log stored in results.xml                                                [0m
[xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Setting the build status to FAILURE
[xUnit] [INFO] - Stopping recording.
Build step 'Publish xUnit test result report' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allright, here's the deal:

Under publish XUnit test results I chose JUnit (also setup the pattern to *.xml) and then
created a shell script to be executed by Jenkins:

```
# Auth tests
for f in auth/*.js ; do casperjs "$f"; done;

# Clean the old results and place the new ones
rm /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/17live2/workspace/*.xml
mv *.xml /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/17live2/workspace/
```

In Jenkins config I just do: `./run.sh`

***You need read/write rights over your folders.